# Override jQuery global selector $ to @

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to override the jQuery selector `$` to `@`. I've seen the source code of jquery but I'm not able to find anything to override the global selector.

In jQuery `window.$` is set to the `jQuery` function

Is there a way to set this to `@`

Comment: Quick question, why do you want to do this?

Comment: To understand how Jquery has used Javascript under the hood concepts. So there must be a way to override the global selector. @AndyHolmes